# How could I even try to analyze map data?

Tags: geostatistics, heatmap

I have a situation where I'm trying to analyze how users interact with maps.

Here's an example to illustrate: Below is an image of Google maps after searching for Chicago, IL pizza.

[image]

Now, say that I want to somehow model how users interact with the map. Is this a standard type of analysis that is done? Are there any good resources or tools or models on how to analyze this type of data? I don't even know where to start.

My thinking was, for example, I might want to see how different features (e.g., the rating that. restaurant has from 1-5) predict the probability of clicking on the pin of different restaurants on the map. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if there are standard analyses and procedures for analyzing this type of data. Seems like there might be a spatial component too.

Any advice or tips would be helpful.

Comment: As written, the question is unanswerable. It's not clear what data you have since, presumably, you don't work at Goggle, and what question you have in mind. [Abhishek Nagaraj](https://abhishekn.com/) has done some interesting work on maps. There are 3 papers linked on his page, which may contain references to academic work that is relevant. In economics, there is a long literature on how consumers use reviews and reputation in product/service search, and also advertising, but nothing in terms of maps that I can recall. The key terms are "demand estimation" and "discrete choice".